# Download de arquivo CSV usando R

Tags: r

Boa tarde pessoal!

como faço para baixar(ler) um arquivo em CSV de um link como esse:

https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239600/ishares-msci-acwi-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=ACWI_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20141231

obrigado!

Comment: Editei sua pergunta olha não mudei o sentido dela. @AndréBlanco

Answer (score 7):

Esse é um ficheiro `CSV` standard mas algumas colunas precisam de processamento posterior.
Tente o seguinte.

```
str2num <- function(x){
    x <- gsub(",", "", x)
    as.numeric(x)
}

URI <- "https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239600/ishares-msci-acwi-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=ACWI_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20141231"
dados <- read.csv(URI, skip = 10, na.strings = c("", "-"))

names(dados)[4] <- "Weight"
cols <- c("Price", "Shares", "Market.Value", "FX.Rate")
dados[cols] <- lapply(dados[cols], str2num)
str(dados)
```

Primeiro lemos o ficheiro com `read.csv`.
De seguida mudei o nome da quarta coluna (é lido como `"Weight...."`).
Finalmente, algumas colunas que parecem ser numéricas devem ser transformadas de classe `factor` para classe `numeric`, com a função auxiliar `str2num`.

**EDIÇÃO**

Na função auxiliar `str2num` tal como originalmente a defini usei `as.character` para transformar a saída de `gsub`. Ora, isso não é necessário uma vez que `gsub` já nos dá vetores de classe `character`. Na secção `Value` da página `help("gsub")` vem (ênfase minha)

> sub and gsub return a **character vector** of the same length and with the
>   same attributes as x (after possible coercion to character).

A função original era a seguinte.

```
str2num <- function(x){
    x <- gsub(",", "", x)
    as.numeric(as.character(x))
}
```

Comment: boa resposta, muito util

Answer (score 4):

A Função **read.csv()**,  já traz da internet o arquivo;

```
 serialize <- read.csv("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239600/ishares-msci-acwi-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=ACWI_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20141231", header = FALSE, sep=",")
```

Para mais informações no link abaixo:
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-txt-csv-files-r-base-functions

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Me parece que o comando da resposta deixa os dados um pouco desorganizados. Eu utilizaria `serialize <- read.csv("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239600/ishares-msci-acwi-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=ACWI_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20141231", header = TRUE, sep=",", skip=10)`, para poder pular as 10 primeiras linhas e ficar com algo mais parecido com o que desconfio que o OP deseja.